# WHY does the this binding break in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, es6-class

I am following a tutorial about es6 classes and React class components. I understand when new class methods are created, the `this` keyword can be used to run other methods in the class and to access the instance properties on that class which makes sense. Here is an example from mdn:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  // Getter
  get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }
  // Method
  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

In React class component methods `this` is again used by event handlers to refer to the event handler method, which tells me the binding at this point inside the render method is still ok. React sample below:

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

As I understand, inside the event handler the binding breaks. I understand how to fix the binding, but what I don't understand is WHY it breaks. A clear, simple explanation to understand this would be appreciated as I'd like to understand. In the render method the `this` binding works as you can access props and state and the event handler and in the es6 sample you can see this being used in different methods without binding, so why not the React event handler?

Comment: Importantly, you can still bind `this.handleClick` to the event handler... you'll notice that it won't fail until you click the button. When rendering, the _call context_ is still the React component. However, this is no longer true when you _click_ the button. On click, you'll get an error that `this.setState` is not defined.

Comment: @Nick I know how to fix the binding and everything you've described but I'm looking for a good clear explanation of the reason WHY the binding breaks, when it doesn't seem to in other ES6 classes and methods and it works in the render method.

Comment: When you’re in the tender method, the call context is the component. When you’re clicking a button, the call context is that button. When you bind this, you say “no matter where this method is called, I want the call context to be the component.”

Comment: Is there any code that can show that? for instance when this is accessed inside the event handler it throws an error...shouldn't it show the button element as it's `this` context instead?

Is this the same thing that would happen in a regular ES6 class with an event handler?

Answer (score 0):

The "this" keyword refers to the global object triggering it.

So in a class(like in a method), it will refer to the instance of the object that was created.

In event handlers, the object that triggers the function is the HTMLElement, because onClick is a method of the HTMLButtonElement.

So the "this" keyword will refer to it.

This is why you have to bind "this", so it will refer to the instance of the class and not to that element.

Comment: So to clarify, what you're saying is when the button is clicked, the event handlers `this` value is the element directly and not the react component instance?

Comment: Exactly. Actually in this case it will not be HTMLButtonElement but the ReactElement object

Comment: Is there a way to show this in code as when you access `this` in an event handler it shows undefined, why doesn't it show the ReactElement object as the context?

Comment: My friend, there is no need to show it in code. It shows undefined because ReactElement object does not have this property (handleClick). If you were to write this.onAbort for example it will NOT show undefined because that object HAS this property. Hope it's understood now. Try and write onClick{console.log(this)} maybe it will clarify it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Practical examples help in understanding. If you have any links which mention this then that would be great too as I didn't find anything.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't work. I tried `onClick={this.onAbort}` and tried to console.log `this` inside the onAbort function if that's what you mean. It came back as undefined.